# How to determine if a JSON response will bind to a model

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

We have a 3rd party service provider that based on a action a notification Webhook is sent to our webhook url using JSON. Due to the fact that i can only provide 1 webhook url all notifications need to funnel to the 1 url. I need to determine which model to deserialze to.

I understand how to deserialize JSON string into an object model.

Here is an example of what is first sent to our webhook

```
{
    "providerAccount": {
        "id": XXXXXX,
        "aggregationSource": "USER",
        "refreshInfo": {
            "statusCode": 801,
            "statusMessage": "ADD_IN_PROGRESS",
            "status": "IN_PROGRESS",
            "additionalStatus": "LOGIN_IN_PROGRESS"
        }
    }
}
```

and then after another 10 or so seconds another JSON webhook comes in.

```
{
    "event": {
        "info": "REFRESH.INTERIM_PROGRESS",
        "loginName": "XXXXXX",
        "data": {
            "providerAccount": {
                "id": XXXXXX,
                "providerId": XXXXXX,
                "isManual": false,
                "createdDate": "2017-12-08",
                "aggregationSource": "USER",
                "refreshInfo": {
                    "status": "IN_PROGRESS",
                    "additionalStatus": "LOGIN_SUCCESS",
                    "statusCode": 0,
                    "statusMessage": "OK",
                    "nextRefreshScheduled": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                    "lastRefreshed": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                    "lastRefreshAttempt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
                },
                "loginForm": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see they would be 2 separate model objects which i need to deserialize.

I find that checking for null on the first model to the second model seems wrong and can be achieved in a different way.

There are another 3 different JSON strings that come through the same webhook. and to check for if model is null, if this model is null etc. then move to next seems wrong.

Comment: you mean you dont have API request pre-decided  format?

Comment: I can only have 1 webhook url, which can inturn have json that can be populated to 4 different models. then i have to determine what process the action is at. So i guess you can say its pre-decided. When the webhook comes in, i need work out which model to populate, then send it via Signal R to the user. Signalr Is working fine BTW

Comment: Do you have any identifire in json for your 4 diffrunt model?

Comment: No the first field comes in as ProviderAccount, the second comes in as "event".

Comment: And what about 3rd and 4th model?

Comment: Do you want to decide which json to deserialize? Why don't you check the root property of the json? Also the Newtonsoft.json dll is great to work with json in c#

Comment: yes i want to be able to decide which JSON to deserialize and which model to populate to send back to the view or what is returned back

Comment: You can use json schema, and validate your input with 4 schemas to find out which model you should deserialize into.

Comment: @Evk can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using the Newtonsoft.json package, which you can install via nuget if you aren't already using it. You can easily accept all JSON requests as a JContainer then check for a field and if that field exists you can deserialize your JSON into the appropriate model.

If you have 4 different models then it would be expected that you'd have 4 semi-unique JSON strings with a different structure that could be identified by checking for a specific field, object or array.

```
   public HttpResponseMessage WebhookCallback(JContainer jsonData)
    {
        // Check to make sure we're getting an object not an array.
        if(jsonData.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            var jObject = jsonData as JObject;

            // If this is an event type object parse it depending on the value of the info field.                
            if(jObject["event"] != null)
            {

                if (jObject["info"] != null && jObject["info"].ToString() == "REFRESH.INTERIM_PROGRESS")
                {
                    InterimProgress interimProgress = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InterimProgress>(jObject["data"].ToString());
                }

                if (jObject["info"] != null && jObject["info"].ToString() == "REFRESH.END_PROGRESS")
                {
                    EndProgress interimProgress = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EndProgress>(jObject["data"].ToString());
                }
            }
            else if (jObject["providerAccount"] != null)
            {
                ProviderAccount providerAccount = jObject.ToObject<ProviderAccount>();
            }
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

If you don't want to deserialize into a JContainer first you could always try to match on a unique key, then deserialize into the correct object.

Comment: Thank you i think that is the way to go

Comment: Overall how can we ever determine what comes in as json, luckly i have some form of results

Answer (score 1):

You can use json schemas to be sure that incoming json indeed matches one of your models exactly. Schemas can be generated from your models (see [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/GeneratingSchemas.htm) for details). Sample code (install `Newtonsoft.Json.Schemas` package):

```
public class ModelMapper {
    private readonly List<SchemaAndHandler> _handlers = new List<SchemaAndHandler>();

    public void AddModelHandler<T>(Func<T, object> handler) {
        // generate schema once
        var schema = new JSchemaGenerator().Generate(typeof(T));
        _handlers.Add(new SchemaAndHandler(schema, typeof(T), o => handler((T) o)));
    }

    public object Parse(string json) {
        var raw = JObject.Parse(json);
        foreach (var handler in _handlers) {
            // validate according to each schema
            if (raw.IsValid(handler.Schema)) {
                return handler.Handler(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, handler.Type));
            }
        }
        // or throw
        return null;
    }

    private class SchemaAndHandler {
        public SchemaAndHandler(JSchema schema, Type type, Func<object, object> handler) {
            Schema = schema;
            Type = type;
            Handler = handler;
        }
        public JSchema Schema { get; }
        public Type Type { get; }
        public Func<object, object> Handler { get; }
    }
}

public class Model1 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Model2 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
// should be reused - no need to create per every request
var mapper = new ModelMapper();
// this also needs to be done only once
mapper.AddModelHandler((Model1 model) => {
    // do something
    return model;
});
mapper.AddModelHandler((Model2 model) => {
    // do something
    return model;
});
// parse incoming json to some result
var result = mapper.Parse("{Name: \"test\"}");
```

If you don't need to do anything specific with parsed model and just need to pass it somewhere, it can be simplified:

```
public class ModelMapper {
    private readonly List<Tuple<Type, JSchema>> _schemas = new List<Tuple<Type, JSchema>>();

    public ModelMapper(params Type[] models) {
        foreach (var model in models) {
            var schema = new JSchemaGenerator().Generate(model);
            _schemas.Add(Tuple.Create(model, schema));
        }
    }

    public object ParseModel(string json) {
        var raw = JObject.Parse(json);
        foreach (var schema in _schemas) {
            // validate according to each schema
            if (raw.IsValid(schema.Item2)) {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, schema.Item1);
            }
        }
        // or throw
        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage is then:

```
// should be reused - no need to create per every request
var mapper = new ModelMapper(typeof(Model1), typeof(Model2));            
var result = mapper.ParseModel("{Name: \"test\"}");
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of the Json objects have different object names, you could extract that name and get c# object type using it, and deserialize to it.

To get object name you can use Newtonsoft.Json package and parse it to JObject, or you could write regex to extract it, in case parsing is too costly for you. Example with JObject:

```
 private string GetJsonObjectName(string json)
    {
        var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);
        return ((JProperty)jobj.First).Name;
    }
```

After having the name you can either add simple switch and get type based on string, or add attribute with Json object name to classes and use reflection.

```
 public class JsonType : Attribute
{
    private string _name;

    public JsonType(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    override
    public string ToString()
    {
        return _name;
    }
}

[JsonType("providerAccount")]
public class RootObjectProvider
{
    public ProviderAccount providerAccount { get; set; }
}
```

Using reflection to get correct object:

```
var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .Where(x => Attribute.IsDefined(x,typeof(JsonType)))
            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(JsonType)).ToString() == jsonObjectName);

var cobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json1, type);
```

Reflection takes longer, but it is easier to extend later on when you add new classes